# How to upload a image to Google Drive Shared folder and get its sharable URL?

Tags: image, web, url, directory

currently I have a working Arduino App that takes a picture, uploads it to a Goggle Drive folder (already made public) and stores some related data on a Google Sheet including the image file name.

But I need to access this data and image from a web app running somewhere else.
The image name "filename.jpg" will not work as part of an URL.

In my current solution two scripts are used:
The first successfully transfers the image.
The second adds a line to the Google Sheet with all the necessary parameters but at this stage all I have is the filename.jpg.

I need to add something to the this second script to get filename.jpg's URL so it can be stored along with the related data on the Google Sheet.

If I could merge the functionality of both scripts in one it would do the job as the transfer script has access to the file ID but I really need help on this one.

Image transfer script:

```
function doPost(e) {
  var myFoldername = e.parameter.myFoldername;
  var myFile = e.parameter.myFile;
  var myFilename = e.parameter.myFilename;
  //var myFilename = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), "GMT", "yyyyMMddHHmmss")+"-"+e.parameter.myFilename;
  var myToken = e.parameter.myToken;
  
  var contentType = myFile.substring(myFile.indexOf(":")+1, myFile.indexOf(";"));
  var data = myFile.substring(myFile.indexOf(",")+1);
  data = Utilities.base64Decode(data);
  var blob = Utilities.newBlob(data, contentType, myFilename);
  
  // Save a captured image to Google Drive.
  var folder, folders = DriveApp.getFoldersByName(myFoldername);
  if (folders.hasNext()) {
    folder = folders.next();
  } else {
    folder = DriveApp.createFolder(myFoldername);
  }
  var file = folder.createFile(blob);    
  file.setDescription("Uploaded by " + myFilename);
  
  var imageID = file.getUrl().substring(file.getUrl().indexOf("/d/")+3,file.getUrl().indexOf("view")-1);
  var imageUrl = "https://drive.google.com/uc?authuser=0&id="+imageID;
    
  // Send a link message to Line Notify.
  var res = "Line Notify: ";
  try {
    var url = 'https://notify-api.line.me/api/notify';
    var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, {
      'headers': {
        'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + myToken,
      },
      'method': 'post',
      'payload': {
          'message': imageUrl
      }
    });
    res += response.getContentText();
  } catch(error) {
    res += error;
  } 
    
  return  ContentService.createTextOutput(myFoldername+"/"+myFilename+"\n"+imageUrl+"\n"+res);
}
```

Google Sheet Script:

```
    var timeZone = "UTC"; //get yours at https://www.timeanddate.com/time/zones/
var dateTimeFormat = "dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm";

var enableSendingEmails = true;
var emailAddress = ""; // comma separate for several emails
// 'bob@example.com';
// 'bob@example.com,admin@example.com';

function doGet(e) {
    var result = 'Ok'; // default result
    if (e.parameter == 'undefined') {
        result = 'No Parameters';
    } else {
      
        var alarm= e.parameter.alarm;
        if (typeof alarm != 'undefined') {

            sendEmail("alarm text:" + stripQuotes(alarm));
            return ContentService.createTextOutput(result);
        }

        var sheet = getSpreadSheet();
        var lastRow = sheet.getLastRow();
        var newRow = 1;
        if (lastRow > 0) {
            var lastVal = sheet.getRange(lastRow, 1).getValue();
          //if there was no info for (sentEmailIfUnitIsOutForMinutes) checkIfDead() function will append row with 'dead' text
          // so checking do we need to override it
            if (lastVal == 'dead')
                newRow = lastRow; //to overwrite "dead" value
            else
                newRow = lastRow + 1;

        }

        var rowData = [];
        var namesOfParams=[];
        for (var param in parseQuery(e.queryString))
          namesOfParams.push(param);
//      namesOfParams=namesOfParams.reverse();
      
      //creatating headers if first row
        if (newRow == 1) {
            rowData[0] = "Date";
            var i = 1;
            for (var i=0; i<namesOfParams.length;i++  ) {
                rowData[i+1] = namesOfParams[i];
            }
            var newRange = sheet.getRange(newRow, 1, 1, rowData.length);
            newRange.setValues([rowData]);
            rowData = [];
            newRow++;
        }

        rowData[0] = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), timeZone, dateTimeFormat);
    
        for (var i=0; i<namesOfParams.length;i++  ) {

          var value = stripQuotes(e.parameter[namesOfParams[i]]);
             
          rowData[i+1] = value;

        }
        var newRange = sheet.getRange(newRow, 1, 1, rowData.length);
        newRange.setValues([rowData]);
    }
    // Return result of operation
    return ContentService.createTextOutput(result);
}


// Remove leading and trailing single or double quotes

function stripQuotes(value) {
    return value.replace(/^["']|['"]$/g, "");
}

function parseQuery(queryString) {
    var query = {};
    var pairs = (queryString[0] === '?' ? queryString.substr(1) : queryString).split('&');
    for (var i = 0; i < pairs.length; i++) {
        var pair = pairs[i].split('=');
        query[decodeURIComponent(pair[0])] = decodeURIComponent(pair[1] || '');
    }
    return query;
}

function sendEmail(message) {
   if (!enableSendingEmails)
        return;
    var subject = 'Something wrong with your esp';
   MailApp.sendEmail(emailAddress, subject, message);
}


function getSpreadSheet() {
    return SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
}
```

Assistance welcome.
Thanks
Paulo

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved with the following script:

```
var timeZone = "GMT";
var dateTimeFormat   = "dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss";
var logSpreadSheetId = "1W1ypQEkfKNFSqhtfgbjbjFgzHO8LDaTv6mNWTP9h4M8"; 
// logSpreadSheetId is to be copied from the sheet's URL as follows: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1W1ypQEkfKNFSqhtfgbjbjFgzHO8LDaTv6mNWTP9h4M8/edit#gid=0

function doPost(e) {
  var myFoldername = e.parameter.myFoldername;
  var myFile = e.parameter.myFile;
  //var myFilename = e.parameter.myFilename;
  //var myFilename = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), timeZone, "ddMMyyyyHHmmss")+"-"+e.parameter.myFilename;
  var myFilename = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), timeZone, "ddMMyyyyHHmmss")+".jpg";
  var myToken    = e.parameter.myToken; 
  
  var contentType = myFile.substring(myFile.indexOf(":")+1, myFile.indexOf(";"));
  var data = myFile.substring(myFile.indexOf(",")+1);
  data = Utilities.base64Decode(data);
  var blob = Utilities.newBlob(data, contentType, myFilename);
  
  // Save a captured image to Google Drive.
  var folder, folders = DriveApp.getFoldersByName(myFoldername);
  if (folders.hasNext()) {
    folder = folders.next();
  } else {
    folder = DriveApp.createFolder(myFoldername);
  }
  var file = folder.createFile(blob);    
  file.setDescription("Uploaded by " + myFilename);
  
  var imageID  = file.getUrl().substring(file.getUrl().indexOf("/d/")+3,file.getUrl().indexOf("view")-1);
  var imageUrl = "https://drive.google.com/uc?authuser=0&id="+imageID;

  addLog(myFilename,imageUrl);
 
  return  ContentService.createTextOutput(myFoldername+"/"+myFilename+"\n"+imageUrl+"\n");  //+res);
}

function addLog(myFilename,imageUrl) {
  var spr   = SpreadsheetApp.openById(logSpreadSheetId);
  var sheet = spr.getSheets()[0];
  var data  = sheet.getDataRange().getValues();
  var pos   = sheet.getLastRow();
  
  var rowData  = [];
  
  if(!pos>0){
    pos = 1;
    rowData[0]   = "Date";
    rowData[1]   = "Image";
    rowData[2]   = "URL";
    var newRange = sheet.getRange(pos, 1, 1, rowData.length);
    newRange.setValues([rowData]);
  } 
  pos     = pos +1;
  rowData = [];
  rowData[0]   = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), timeZone, dateTimeFormat);
  rowData[1]   = myFilename;
  rowData[2]   = imageUrl;
  var newRange = sheet.getRange(pos, 1, 1, rowData.length);
  newRange.setValues([rowData]);
}
```

Also, for simplicity, the sheet and the script now sit on independent files as the script can refer to the sheet using its ID as in: var logSpreadSheetId = "1W1ypQEkfKNFSqhtfgbjbjFgzHO8LDaTv6mNWTP9h4M8"; (Please used the ID of your own sheet).